# Cannot denormalize array

Tags: symfony, serialization

```
class Item
{
   public $id;

   //..getters and setters
}
$data = [['id' => 1], ['id' => 2]];

$serializer = new Serializer([new GetSetMethodNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer()]);
$model = $serializer->denormalize($data, "Item[]");
dump($model);die;
```

And I'm getting error:

`Could not denormalize object of type Item[], no supporting normalizer found.`

All like in this example - https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html#handling-arrays 
Why I'm getting error?

Answer (score 8):

I use it like this:

### Handling Arrays

The Serializer component is capable of handling arrays of objects as well. Serializing arrays works just like serializing a single object:

```
use Acme\Person;

$person1 = new Person();
$person1->setName('foo');
$person1->setAge(99);
$person1->setSportsman(false);

$person2 = new Person();
$person2->setName('bar');
$person2->setAge(33);
$person2->setSportsman(true);

$persons = array($person1, $person2);
$data = $serializer->serialize($persons, 'json');

// $data contains [{"name":"foo","age":99,"sportsman":false},{"name":"bar","age":33,"sportsman":true}]
```

If you want to deserialize such a structure, you need to add the [`ArrayDenormalizer`](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Normalizer/ArrayDenormalizer.html) to the set of normalizers. By appending [] to the type parameter of the [deserialize()](http://api.symfony.com/3.3/Symfony/Component/Serializer/Serializer.html#method_deserialize) method, you indicate that you're expecting an array instead of a single object.

```
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Encoder\JsonEncoder;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\ArrayDenormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Normalizer\GetSetMethodNormalizer;
use Symfony\Component\Serializer\Serializer;

$serializer = new Serializer(
    array(new GetSetMethodNormalizer(), new ArrayDenormalizer()),
    array(new JsonEncoder())
);

$data = ...; // The serialized data from the previous example
$persons = $serializer->deserialize($data, 'Acme\Person[]', 'json');
```

**Read more here:** https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/serializer.html

Comment: what's the point of copying the sf docs here? the author is even linking it himself!

Answer (score 0):

I am injecting in factory the Denormalizer I need:

```
...factory class 
public function __construct(AbstractObjectNormalizer $normalizer)
{   
    $this->normalizer = $normalizer;
}

...

public function create(array $value)
{
    return $this->normalizer->denormalize($value, Item::class);
}
```